# Exportar do pandas para o MS SQL usando to_sql e sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Meu problema é com valores Float

exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.45])

conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)

df.to_sql(name='teste',con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

a tabela é gerada no meu SQL com sucesso, o problema é o formato do float que vem com virgula em vez de ponto (1,45)
como eu faço para exportar com separador por ponto(1.45)

obs: em outras tabelas do meu banco estão com separador por ponto

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Use *locale*:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, str('en_US.UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Oi Marcelo, desculpa a ignorância, mas não entendi em qual parte eu uso esse código.

Comment: No _entry point_ do seu programa. No início dele.